# Indoor maps - How to track user location and directions using Indoor maps - Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, maps, apple-maps

I developing app in both iOS and Android which requires Indoor Maps feature. Using Indoor maps we need to track user location, which floor user is in (in case if user is in shopping mall or multi-storey building and  which directions user is moving. So, i request to please provide any information to achieve above tasks.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I have worked on a project that tried to achieve this, so this is more of a personal anecdote.

With GPS: It's not going to happen. GPS is way too inaccurate to achieve this kind of precision.

Other ways: There are multiple ways that you might be able to achieve this, look into triangulating with Wifi. For the project that I worked in we used our own 'nodes' that were positioned in the building.

So in conclusion:

You can't do this with google-maps or apple-maps.

Also:

Please try to ask a more specific question the next time and show what you have already tried.